# Need to change the legend to decimal values

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using this code to generate boxplots. I want the legend to be continuos, not discrete. Also, the boxplot colour needs to be different for each value of SOP(this is in increments of .5).

```
brk1 <- seq(from = 0.5, to = 5.5, by = .5)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = SOP, y = Chance.of.Admit)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = SOP, group = SOP)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = brk1)
```

[image: My Boxplots]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you share a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

In the current plot as the `fill` is continous variable it is already different color for each `SOP` value though it hard for human eyes to detect the differences. If you want to have different color can try different type in the `scale_fill_continous` such as `type = "viridis"`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create a random sample data
data <- tibble(
  SOP = sample(seq(1, 5, by = 0.5), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  Chance.of.Admit = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)
)

brk1 <- seq(from = 0.5, to = 5.5, by = .5)

# Using scale_fill_continuous with breaks option 
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = SOP, y = Chance.of.Admit)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = SOP, group = SOP)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = brk1) +
  scale_fill_continuous(breaks = brk1,
    type = "viridis")
```

[image]

I understand you don't want a discrete legend though it may worth have a looked.

```r
# Create the colors scale coresponded to the SOP
color_scales_fn <- colorRampPalette(c("#173f5f", "#20639b", "#3caea3",
  "#f6d55c", "#ed553b"))
sop_list <- sort(unique(data$SOP))
manual_color <- color_scales_fn(length(sop_list))
names(manual_color) <- sop_list
# Using scale_fill_manual with new color palletes
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = SOP, y = Chance.of.Admit)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = as.character(SOP), group = SOP)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = brk1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = manual_color, name = "SOP")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>